# Problems with UNION SQL command - JSON not returning PHP variable to AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, json, union

I'm dev a ratings script. I need to update SQL and then find an average based on criteria (storyidr). With the following script I'm getting {"status":"fail"} from AJAX after it's triggered. I need to be reporting the value $avrank.

```
    $storyidr=$_POST['storyidr'];
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
       {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now());"; 
    $sql .= "SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank from ratings WHERE storyidr = $storyidr";
    if($mysqli->multi_query($sql))
    {   
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result())
    { 
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $avrank = $data['avrank'];
            if(!$result)
            {
                  $arr = array ('status'=>'fail');
                  echo json_encode($arr);
            }
            else
            {

                    echo json_encode($avrank);
            }
                    exit;
    }
    }
```

here's what I'm using in AJAX, but i don't think the issue is there:

```
   $.ajax({
             url: '../rate.php',
             data: { storyidr: storyidr, value: value }, 
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
             },
             error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                 $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
             }
         });
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: sql injection alert! :D

Comment: Check your query if it is working

Comment: the subqueries of a union have to be `SELECT` queries. You can't have a `UNION` between an `INSERT` and a `SELECT`. You have to do them as separate queries.

Comment: its not working. The two parts work separately but Union does not allow combination.

Comment: Baramar, is there a more fitting command I could use here?

Comment: Why not just separate your queries? You could have different parameters to convey whether both the queries were successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$sql .= "INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now());"
$sql .= "SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank from ratings WHERE storyidr=$storyidr;"

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);

for more info go to https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: The code isn't working (some syntax errors) but I think you may be on the right track. I'm reading up on it and trying find the errors. What the arrow indicate?

Comment: mysqli basically used for object oriented programming. So the arrow here to access the instance methods or variables

Comment: I posted new code, nothing I do can get rid of the mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given error

Comment: have you gone through this part do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());